# Sum tuples if identical values

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here's my list of tuples:

```
regions = [(23.4, 12, 12341234), 
           (342.23, 19, 12341234), 
           (4312.3, 12, 12551234), 
           (234.2, 12, 12341234)]
```

I'm trying to sum the first index value in a list of tuples where the values at indices 1 and 2 are identical.  Note that regions[0] and regions[3] have the same values at indices 1 and 2.

My desired list is:

```
result = [(257.6, 12, 12341234), 
          (342.23, 19, 12341234), 
          (4312.3, 12, 12551234)]
```

I realize that I probably need to save it as a dictionary first, probably with the second value as the first key and the third value as the second key and summing if it already exists.  Just wondering if there's a better or easier way: I'm thinking maybe using some intersect function.

Comment: Does the ordering of tuples in the result matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(float)
for c, a, b in regions:
    sums[a, b] += c
result = [(csum, a, b) for (a, b), csum in sums.iteritems()]
```

There isn't a built-in function to do this; it's far too specialized a task.

Comment: Beat me to it - and more completely :)

Comment: and is `.iteritems()` better/different than `.items()`?

Comment: `.iteritems()` is for Python 2 and I believe returns a generator. In Python 3 `.iteritems()` does not exist. @bozdoz

Comment: you could drop `()`. A tuple is created by a comma (`,`): `for a, b, c in regions: results[b,c] += a`. You could also unpack in the for-loop: `result = [(a, b, c) for (b, c), a in sums.items()]`. Or `result = [(a,) + t for t, a in sums.items()]`